# Why is emailVerified in next-auth a datetime value and not a boolean?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

In the `next-auth` documentation `emailVerified` is written as `DateTime` in the `User model`. See for example the [Prisma implementation](https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/prisma).

However, I realised a `boolean` is returned instead in case of a Google implementation.
If it is written by mistake as a wrong type, they were pretty consistent throughout their documentation. In examples I found I see the DateTime field as well. Am I overlooking something? Or did I just realise a mistake in their docs?